# Loop through a complex JSON structure using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I can access my desired field from a JSON object like so:

`<li ng-repeat='customer in customers[0][data]["DisplayName"] | filter:search'>{{ customer }}</li>`

However, that only returns one object's property.

Using AngularJS, is there a way to loop through the following?

```
customers[0][data]["DisplayName"]
customers[1][data]["DisplayName"]
customers[2][data]["DisplayName"]
customers[3][data]["DisplayName"]
customers[4][data]["DisplayName"]
...
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the JSON?

Comment: Visit http://persianturtle.com/app and open up the console.  It will be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`customers` is an array, so by doing `ng-repeat` you will already loop through it. But I think what you want is either: 1) show the `DisplayName` property inside `<li>` or 2) filter by `DisplayName`.

To show the nested property, do the following

```
<li ng-repeat="customer in customers">
  {{ customer[data]["DisplayName"] }}
</li>
```

To filter on nested property, for example on `DisplayName`:

```
<li ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:{data: {DisplayName: search}}">
  ...
</li>
```